# Image Processing on Vivado HLS

Tags: image-processing, http-live-streaming

I'm working on video processing project. At the initial stage, I started with a simple program with importing an image and just duplicate it in the main function and pass it back. It works but the resultant image is not what I put.

Here are my files and attached images.

**image_filter.h**

```
#ifndef _TOP_H_
#define _TOP_H_
#include "hls_video.h"
#include <ap_axi_sdata.h>
#define MAX_WIDTH 256
#define MAX_HEIGHT 256
// Image file path
#define INPUT_IMAGE_CORE "D:\\IMP_PRACTICE\\cameraman.bmp"
#define OUTPUT_IMAGE_CORE "D:\\IMP_PRACTICE\\cameraman_res.bmp"
typedef hls::stream<ap_axiu<8,1,1,1> > AXI_STREAM;
typedef hls::Mat<MAX_HEIGHT, MAX_WIDTH, HLS_8UC1> IMAGE_8;
//typedef hls::Scalar<2, unsigned char> PIXEL_8;
typedef unsigned char data_t;

typedef ap_axiu<8,1,1,1> uint_8_side_channel;

void image_filter(AXI_STREAM &INPUT_STREAM, AXI_STREAM &OUTPUT_STREAM, int rows, int cols);
#endif
```

**image_filter.cpp**

```
#include "image_filter.h"
void image_filter(AXI_STREAM &video_in, AXI_STREAM &video_out, int rows, int cols)
{
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=video_in bundle=INPUT_STREAM
#pragma HLS INTERFACE axis port=video_out bundle=OUTPUT_STREAM
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=rows bundle=CONTROL_BUS //offset=0x14
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=cols bundle=CONTROL_BUS //offset=0x1c
#pragma HLS INTERFACE s_axilite port=return bundle=CONTROL_BUS

IMAGE_8 img_0(rows, cols);
IMAGE_8 img_1(rows, cols);
IMAGE_8 img_2(rows, cols);
#pragma HLS dataflow

hls::AXIvideo2Mat(video_in, img_0);
hls::Duplicate(img_0, img_1, img_2);
hls::Mat2AXIvideo(img_1, video_out);
```

}

**test_image_filter.cpp**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <hls_opencv.h>
#include "image_filter.h"

// Image File path
char outImage[MAX_WIDTH][MAX_HEIGHT];
void saveImage(const std::string path, cv::InputArray inArr)
{
double min;
double max;
cv::minMaxIdx(inArr, &min, &max);
cv::Mat adjMap;
cv::convertScaleAbs(inArr, adjMap, 255 / max);
cv::imwrite(path,adjMap);
}
int main()
{
// Read input image
printf("Load image %s\n",INPUT_IMAGE_CORE);
cv::Mat imageSrc;
imagesrc=cv::imread(INPUT_IMAGE_CORE);
// Convert to grayscale
cv::cvtColor(imageSrc, imageSrc, CV_BGR2GRAY);
printf("Image Rows:%d Cols:%d\n",imageSrc.rows, imageSrc.cols);
// Define streams for input and output
AXI_STREAM inputStream;
AXI_STREAM outputStream;
// OpenCV mat that point to a array (cv::Size(Width, Height))
cv::Mat imgCvOut(cv::Size(imageSrc.cols, imageSrc.rows), CV_8UC1, outImage, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
// Populate the input stream with the image bytes
for (int idxRows=0; idxRows < imageSrc.rows; idxRows++)
{
    for (int idxCols=0; idxCols < imageSrc.cols; idxCols++)
    {
        uint_8_side_channel valIn;
        valIn.data = imageSrc.at<unsigned char>(idxRows,idxCols);
        valIn.keep = 1; valIn.strb = 1; valIn.user = 1; valIn.id = 0; valIn.dest = 0;
inputStream << valIn;
    }
}

printf("Calling Core function\n");
image_filter(inputStream, outputStream, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);
printf("Core function ended\n");
// Take data from the output stream to our array outImage (Pointed in opencv)
for (int idxRows=0; idxRows < imageSrc.rows; idxRows++)
{
    for (int idxCols=0; idxCols < imageSrc.cols; idxCols++)
    {
        uint_8_side_channel valOut;
outputStream.read(valOut);
outImage[idxRows][idxCols] = valOut.data;
    }
}
// Save image out file or display
saveImage(std::string(OUTPUT_IMAGE_CORE) ,imgCvOut);
return 0;
}
```

---

The resultant image "cameraman_res.bmp" is totally different from the input image "cameraman.bmp".

Can anyone please highlight what mistakes I'm doing in this code?

Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

if you want the same image back, why you add this to your code?

```
cv::convertScaleAbs(inArr, adjMap, 255 / max);
```